# Can I get federated end of participant info with UCWA app on my end?

Tags: skype-for-business, federation, ucwa

I'm planning to create a chatbot application for SfB Server with UCWA. This bot will be invited by my partner's SfB online user's chat meeting, then provide some background services. The partner's O365 tenant and my SfB server is federated.

I'd like to collect my partner end of participant information such as user uri for my service purpose(assumed that the partner agreed to provide those info to us). Does someone know if I can get participant info from federated organization hosted chat conf which out chat bot has been invited?

If yes, is the [participant] resource is the right one to use?